# Mysql Trigger with Subquery on slave

Tags: mysql, triggers, subquery

i have some triggers on slave machine.
it doesn't triggering with sub query.
Without subquery it works.

Thanks

```
INSERT INTO s_address (lastname,address,telephone,city)
  VALUES('yilmaz','my new address','905548185555',
   (SELECT `city_name` FROM s_city WHERE city_id='58')
 ) ;



DELIMITER $$
   CREATE TRIGGER `s_address_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON 
  `s_address` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.lastname = mask_lastname(NEW.lastname);
   SET NEW.address = mask_address(NEW.address);
   SET NEW.telephone = mask_tel(NEW.telephone);
END$$
```

Comment: Does the insert works ? Because i wouldn't write the insert like this.

Comment: yes Daniel, Insert works